# How to find out the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to solve the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+b^2)^{3/2}(x+a^2)^{1/2}}$$

I tried it via partial fraction but calculations goes out of my reach. So is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\geq 0$, if $a^2\not=b^2$,  the integrand 
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{(x+b^2)^{3/2}(x+a^2)^{1/2}}
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+a^2}{x+b^2}\right)^{-1/2}\cdot\frac{2}{(x+b^2)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+a^2}{x+b^2}\right)^{-1/2}\cdot\frac{(x+b^2)-(x+a^2)}{(x+b^2)^2}\cdot\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}
\end{align*}
is the derivative of
$$\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}\cdot\left(\frac{x+a^2}{x+b^2}\right)^{1/2}.$$ 
Hence for $|b|>0$,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+b^2)^{3/2}(x+a^2)^{1/2}}=\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}\left[\left(\frac{x+a^2}{x+b^2}\right)^{1/2}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}\left(1-\frac{|a|}{|b|}\right)=\frac{2}{|b|(|a|+|b|)}.$$
If $a^2=b^2>0$ then
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+a^2)^{2}}=\left[-\frac{1}{x+a^2}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{a^2}.$$
So the formula $\dfrac{2}{|b|(|a|+|b|)}$ holds also in this case.

Comment: But how to do this without knowing the derivative?

Comment: @MittalG I tried to give you an idea of how to re-write the integrand.